# Accept path from user to store file in that entered location in Python

Tags: python, wxpython

i would like the user to select the path or the location , so that the file can be stored at that location when the user clicks a button.
I want something similar to the File Explorer we have in Java.
Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to create a file using csv.write and store it in the location entered by the user ie I need te user to select the location where he would like to download the file. for eg Mydesktop or Mydocuments

Comment: Are you looking for [`wx.FileDialog`](http://wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.FileDialog-class.html)?

Comment: Burhan Khalid - I think what you suggested is what I need. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently developing a GUI using wxPython and found [this website](http://zetcode.com/wxpython/) really useful .

It gives information and code samples for most of all the basic capabilities of wxPython.

[Here is the complete ebook](http://www.scribd.com/doc/62314492/The-WxPython-Tutorial) (containing a file dialog example)

Check it out, it's worth it ;)